# Textbox output that depends on the selection in dropdown

Tags: javascript, html

I need to output an amount in a textbox whatever the user chooses in the drop down menu. I have these lines of code, but it doesn't change answer. 
For example, if the user chooses A, then an answer will be shown in the textbox, if s/he chose B, a different answer will be shown.

**script**

```
$(function(){
   $('select[name="Menu"] == A').change(function(){
       var textId= $(this).data('text');
       $('#'+textId).val("$186.00");  
   });
});

$(function(){
    $('select[name="Menu"] == B').change(function(){
        var textId= $(this).data('text');
        $('#'+textId).val("$200.00");  
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<select name="Menu" data-text="inptxt1">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
    <option value="D">D</option>
</select>
</select>

<input type="text" value="$0.00" name="inptxt1" id="inptxt1" readonly/>
```

Comment: and what is your question?

Comment: what is wrong with my script??? or is it possible that i can use a conditional statement here? because the answer in the text box won't changed even though  i have chosen a different option in the drop down menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix your code you want to listen to the `change` event on the `SELECT` element, not the `OPTION`. This is especially easy with jQuery because you can use `.val()` to get the selected value when it changes, like this:

```
$("select[name='Menu']").change(function()
{ 
  var selectedValue = $(this).val();
  // do stuff with selectedValue (in this case 'A', B', 'C', etc.)
});
```

You usually want your price information, which may vary as time goes on, to be dynamic and data-driven, not hard-coded into a conditional statement or the markup.

Scroll down to bottom and click "Run Snippet" to see this in action. It shows how multiple options affect the cost, which sounds like what you are ultimately after.

```js
// dynamic product data comes from server (for example, on initial load or via AJAX)
var products = [{
  Code: 'A',
  Price: 100.00,
  Description: 'Large'
}, {
  Code: 'B',
  Price: 125.00,
  Description: 'X-Large'
}, {
  Code: 'C',
  Price: 150.00,
  Description: 'XX-Large'
}, {
  Code: 'D',
  Price: 1000.00,
  Description: 'WTF-Large'
}];

function RefreshProductInfo() {
  var qty = parseInt($("#ddlQty").val());
  var productCode = $("#Menu").val();
  var items = $.grep(products, function(item) {
    return item.Code === productCode;
  });
  if (items.length === 1) {
    var product = items[0];
  } else {
    product = {
      Price: 0.0
    };
  }
  $("#lblPrice").text(product.Price.toFixed(2));
  var cost = product.Price * qty;
  $("#lblCost").text(cost.toFixed(2));
}

// populate products options
$.each(products, function(idx, item) {
  $("#Menu").append($("<option></option").val(item.Code).text(item.Description));
});

// populate qty options
var maxQty = 10;
var stringBuffer = [];
for (var i = 0; i < maxQty; i++) {
  stringBuffer[i] = "<option>" + (i + 1) + "</option>";
}
$("#ddlQty").on("change", RefreshProductInfo).html(stringBuffer.join());
$("#Menu").on("change", RefreshProductInfo);
```

```css
* {
  font-family: "Segoe UI", Arial, "Sans serif";
  font-size: 14px;
}
LABEL {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 4px;
  text-align: right;
}
SPAN {
  color: #333;
  padding: 4px;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  <label for="Menu">Size:</label>
  <select id="Menu">
    <option value="">[Choose size]</option>
  </select>
</p>
<p>
  <label for="lblPrice">Unit price:</label>
  $<span id="lblPrice">0.00</span>
</p>
<p>
  <label for="ddlQty">Qty:</label>
  <select id="ddlQty"></select>
</p>
<p>
  <label for="lblCost">Gross cost:</label>
  $<span id="lblCost">0.00</span>
</p>
```

Comment: Stackoverflow: ask a question about jquery, get a web app for an answer. brilliant!

Answer (score 0):

You need to detect the change on the select rather than the option.

**Fiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/ghopkins/o43dnbgh/

**Script**

```
$(function(){
    $('select[name="Menu"]').change(function(){
        var textId= $(this).data('text');
        var price = $( "option:selected" , this).data('price');
        $('#'+textId).val(price);  
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<select name="Menu" data-text="inptxt1">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="A" data-price="$186.00">A</option>
    <option value="B" data-price="$200.00">B</option>
    <option value="C" data-price="$214.00">C</option>
    <option value="D" data-price="$228.00">D</option>
</select>

<input type="text" value="$0.00" name="inptxt1" id="inptxt1" readonly/>
```

Edited to put back data attributes, silly me..

Comment: Simple straightforward solution. +1

Comment: how about, if there's another option in "A"? like for example, there are two drop down menus. how will the code go if the condition is like this if "A" is chosen, and in the other dropdown "1" is chosen, then an output will be shown in textbox. its like the output will only be shown when the two dropdown becomes true

Comment: The other way you had it was better (with data attributes). The reason: if this were an e-commerce system you would not submit the price from client to server; the price would be set on server and the client would just give the code (A, B, etc.). Otherwise client could spoof a POST request and pass `0.0` for the price. Using the data attributes was a cleaner separation of logic. Especially since price is a currency amount and if you were to internationalize this web application you wouldn't want to be tied to US currency (for example).

Comment: I've put the price data attributes in, i agree @nothingisnecessary

Answer (score -1):

I don't think `'select[name="Menu"] == A'` is a legal jQuery selector.  I suggest making a selector that just finds the dropdown menu, and then checking for the value, which you can do in a single function:

```
$('select[name="Menu"]').change(function() {
  var textId = $(this).data('text');
  var textValue;
  if $(this).val() == "A"
    textValue = "$186.00";
  else if $(this).val() == "B"
    textValue = "$200.00";
  end
  $('#' + textId).val(textValue);  
});
```

Comment: how about if there is another condition... like, if `$(this).val() == "A" || "1"` and there will be an output in txtbox1 and txtbox2, but different answers. is it correct if i put it this way 
`$(this).val() == "A" || "1" 
document.getElementById("inptxt1").innerHTML = "$186.00";
document.getElementById("inptxt2").innerHTML = "$200.00";`

Comment: Actually, `select[name="menu"]` *is* a valid jQuery selector.

Comment: For sure, @God, the selector you gave is OK, it's the version with `==` that looks wrong to me.

Comment: @anna, I don't understand your suggested code `"A" || "1"`, but you can certainly examine the value `$(this).val()` and trigger any changes on the other controls as you like.

Comment: @anna you can always use ```$(this).text()``` on the ```<option></option>``` tag. that way you can check the option name. in that case you can do ```if ($(this).text().trim() === "A") do something```

Answer (score -1):

i don't think its necessary to put a data attribute on the select options. just use value for the monetary value and the html text field for the option text.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lt6htect/)

```
<select name="Menu" data-text="inptxt1">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="$186.00">A</option>
    <option value="$200.00">B</option>
    <option value="$214.00">C</option>
    <option value="$228.00">D</option>
</select>

<input type="text" value="$0.00" name="inptxt1" id="inptxt1" readonly/>
```

javascript:

```
$(function(){
    $('select[name="Menu"]').change(function(){
        var textId= $(this).data('text');
        var price = $( "option:selected").val();
        $('#'+textId).val(price);  
    });
});
```

Comment: I've edited my question to get rid of data attributes, good point.

Comment: it is not a fix value. the "A" option in dropdown menu1 have many values. actually there's a second dropdown menu in every option in dropdown menu1.

Comment: No, no, this is bad style. For one thing, two options could have the same price in which case `value` is ambiguous. Value should be the product code, which is what you would send to server (perhaps in addition to quantity); price is an attribute of the product, and should be read-only (presentation layer) so that it is easy to show price in other currencies, and easy to change the price over time, etc.

Comment: @nothingisnecessary please don't downvote because of your opinion on style. the question doesn't say anything about server side validation. i answered the question in a very concise manner. if you want to get the option name you can use the .text() method in jquery. i hope you didn't downvote everyone on this for your incredibly over the top answer.

Comment: This site's audience ranges from novices to experts. For the novices especially it is a good idea to promote best practices and avoid problematic ones that result in less maintainable code. A lot of folks start programming by copy and paste and when lousy examples are copied it results in more lousy programs out in the world that people like me eventually have to fix.